# How can i make a method stop and start over again in Java

Tags: java, methods

The title says it all, is there a way to stop a method from continuing and making it start over again from its start?

```
public class Numbers {
    static Scanner numberScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int answer;

    public static int insertNumbers(int num1, int num2) {
        System.out.println("Insert two numbers");
        num1 = numberScanner.nextInt();
        if (numberScanner.hasNext()) {
            num2 = numberScanner.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Equation format incorrect");
            //stop method and start over again from "Insert two numbers".
        }
        answer = num1 + num2;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: What could be input here? If you are reading the numbers inside the method then no need to pass then as parameter to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i propose:

in the else case, you just use this construction

```
else{

    System.out.println("Equation format incorrect");

    return insertNumbers();
}
```

Please be aware the code will keep on asking input until the input is two numbers. No need for the arguments in the method declaration, since you don't use them

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to returning an exit code or using a loop (which is what I believe is more obvious because you can use `continue`), you can call the function again and prevent the original instance from going further:

```
public int foo(){
    //do stuff
    if (must_restart){
        return foo();
        //or, if the function "returns" void: (note that 2 returns/having statements after a return is pointless, this is just an example)
        foo();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return immediately from that point, by returning an int grom the method, eg -1 if not correct and you know you need to retry, or 0 if correct. In the calling code, you can call this method in a loop until the return code == 0.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

Read the numbers in the method, no need to pass them as parameter. Read as them in a loop until both the number are inputted correctly then break. If wrong input then print the message and read again. For any wrong input Scanner.nextInt() will throw `InputMismatchException` exception and there we will also consume the new line character from that input.

```
public static int insertNumbers() {
  int num1;
  int num2;
  while(true) {      // loop until correct input.
    System.out.println("Insert two numbers");
    try {
      num1 = numberScanner.nextInt();
      num2 = numberScanner.nextInt();
      break;        // break once correct input is recorded.
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      System.out.println("Equation format incorrect");  // print message and repeat again for input.
      numberScanner.nextLine();
    }
  }
  answer = num1 + num2;
  return answer;  // return the results.
}
```